# I am getting an error saying Undefined offset: 1 in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this code in my controller:

```
$postlist->phaseList = $this->Project->LatestApplicablePlan->WBS->GetPhaseList($Options);
$PhaseList = $this->Project->LatestApplicablePlan->WBS->GetPhaseList($Options);

$postlist->Counter = COUNT($PhaseList);

for($x = 0; $x < COUNT($PhaseList); $x++)
{
    foreach($PhaseList as $row) {
        $TaskID = array( $row['TaskID'] );
        $postlist->taskList = $this->Project->LatestApplicablePlan->WBS->GetWBS($TaskID[$x], $Options);
    }
}
```

But I am getting an error saying `undefined offset : 1`. The data I was retrieving in the database is many not only a single data.

Answer (score 2):

The problem comes from this line :

```
$TaskID = array( $row['TaskID'] );
```

This is the equivalent of writing :

```
$TaskID = array(
    0 => $row['TaskID'] 
);
```

As you can there is only 1 element in the array `TaskID` so when your `$x` becomes greater than zero, your error appears.

Try this :

```
$PhaseList = $this->Project->LatestApplicablePlan->WBS->GetPhaseList($Options);

$postlist->phaseList = $PhaseList;
$postlist->Counter = COUNT($PhaseList);

foreach($PhaseList as $row) {
    $postlist->taskList[] = $this->Project->LatestApplicablePlan->WBS->GetWBS($row['TaskID'], $Options);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering sir :). i have another problem again.

$postlist->taskList = $this->Project->LatestApplicablePlan->WBS->GetWBS($row['TaskID'], $Options); I've tried this. but it only process the last data its like it didnt get over to all the data..

ive tried var_dump $row['TaskID'] and the result is this:
string(1) "1" 
string(2) "21" 
string(2) "29" 
string(2) "20" 
string(2) "78" 
string(2) "92"

It only gets the 92.

Comment: I've edited my answer. I've transformed `$postlist->taskList[]` to an array. This is where the problem you described came from.